# Date formatter function gives me a negative number

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have this piece of code

```
function dateFormatter(date) {

var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);
var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);

if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " Years Ago ";
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " Months Ago ";
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " Days Ago ";
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " Hrs ago ";
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " mins ago ";
}
return Math.floor(seconds) + " seconds ago";
```

}

it works fine but for some of the times it gives me a negative number, i'm fetching last tweets from twitter and wanna custom date.
right now i have a tweet with `21:08:49 GMT-0400 (EDT)` date but what i'm getting is `-4733 SECONDS AGO`

Any idea what's going on here?
Any help would be appreciated.

Updated code:

```
var d = new Date(g[b].getAttribute("datetime").replace(/-/g, "/").replace("T", "  ").split("+")[0]),
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that the date you pass as argument is "newer" than the current date. This would make sense, because your interval would then always be less than one and you would skip al the if clauses always returning the answer in seconds.

Maybe you are using different timezones? Try to log the two dates to the console `console.log(...)` and you will know if you have to look any further.

Comment: You right it happens when the time is in the future  :D I just added the new code take a look i think that would be a source of issue

Comment: Glad I could help :) I guess it's just a problem of timezones that are not converted correctly

Comment: Can i do anything to prevent it? Did you see my updated code?

Comment: I don't know what your updated code does. But for the timezone problem you could convert both dates to UTC time. Assuming you know the timezone of the date you get from twitter. I think this can be useful: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/ If you don't get the timezone in the date. You could deduce it manually by comparing the date of a fresh post to your current date. Normally there should be n-hours of difference. And then adjust the date to your timezone. This assumes that the timezone is constant for the twitter posts.